# Не запускается сервер на tomcat на VPS'e

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Мне нужно сделать клиент-серверное приложение используя *RESTful API*.

Я в этой теме новичок, поэтому решил за основу своего приложения взять исходный код из [этих](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78cxoEKrROs&t=2s) видеокурсов от *Devcolibri*.

Теперь мне нужно этот сервак закинуть на *VPS*, поэтому я зарегистрировался на *DigitalOcean* и настроил там *VPS*. Я это всё делаю впервые, поэтому мог ошибиться где-то.  Я поставил на *VPS* *Ubuntu* *JRE*, *JDK*, *Tomcat*, *PostgreSQL*.
Также залил в папку `tomcat/webapps` свой *WAR* файл из *IDIA*, чтобы произошел деплой.

Я целый день гуглил инструкцию, как же залить свой сервак на *Java* + *Spring* на *VPS* и как его настроить. Везде по кусочкам инфу собирал и теперь застрял. Не знаю, что делать дальше. Запускаю *Tomcat* и вижу стартовую страницу.
Если запускаю *Tomcat* локально, через *IDEA*, то получаю *JSON* по такому урлу: `localhost:8080/reminders`.

На _VPS_е пробую по такому урлу: `мой_ip:8080/remindmeserv/reminders`
и по такому: `мой_ip:8080/reminders`, но ни один из них не работает, выходит ошибка 404 от *Tomcat*.

В *Tomcat Web Application Manager* увидел свой `war` или папку с сервером. Нажимаю START, но выходит ошибка `FAIL - Application at context path /remindmeserv could not be started`.

Уже не знаю, что делать чтобы сервер заработал. Не знаю даже что гуглить. Где и как.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема? Почему не запускается сервер? *WAR* был задеплоен. Может быть ссылку на какой-нибудь тутор кинете?

---

Выкладываю сюда настройки db.properties и hibernate.properties, чтобы читаемость кода была лучше

```
db.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
db.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/reminderdb
db.username = postgres
db.password = kasya010203
db.entity.package = com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity

db.initialSize = 30
db.minIdle = 30
db.maxIdle = 60
db.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 30000
db.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
db.testOnBorrow = true
db.validationQuery = select version()
```

db properties:

```
hibernate.dialet = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create
```

Comment: Посмотрите логи на VPS - может что-то станет яснее. Например могут быть не настроены права доступа к файловой системы для юзера, из под коего томкат запускается. Или они настроены, но пути к файлам в программе абсолютные, а у юзера доступ не ко всей файловой системе, а только к определённым папкам.

Comment: с правами вроде все ок, я под root'ом сижу, пути в basrc не выходят за папку root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У *Tomcat* есть админка, в которой просто закидываешь файл `war` и нажимаешь деплой. Находится она по адресу: твой `ip сервера:8080`.

Если ты все правильно настроил и завел пользователя под админскими правами, то сможешь зайти. А там все просто.  Если же по этому адресу ничего нет, убедись что *Tomcat* запущен `service tomcat status`. По необходимости ребутни `service tomcat restart`.

Comment: УРА!!! Я РАЗОБРАЛСЯ! Спасибо Android_EE! Оказывается просто у меня WAR не деплоился из-за того что он не мог подключиться к базе. Всё просто как оказалось

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66052/discussion-on-answer-by-android-ee-----tomcat--vpse).